# Why is this condition comparing dates returning true?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column full Dates and I am trying to highlight all of the dates if they are before 30 before todays date.

An example of why what I have that is not working is the value in the cell is 4/12/2017 and it is being highlighted when only values before 4/01/2017 should be highlighted (today is 5/01/2017).

My rule in conditional formatting is

```
Format only cells with:
cell value     less than     =Today()-30
  *change background color*
```

but the 04/12/2017 is still being highlighted.

Comment: Your date formatting might be dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 1):

Select the first cell in the range you need to format, then put that cell into the formula.  For example, if you select A1 change the formula to:

```
=A1<TODAY()-30
```

Then click OK and check your 'applies to' range.

You probably also want to filter out blank cells.  For this you can change the formula to:

```
=AND(A1<TODAY()-30,A1<>"")
```